# Virtualization- How to gain Hands- On experience

Tags: virtualization

I  m trying to understand the concepts in Virtualization.  I guess getting my feet wet with some free ware products would be a wise move. Any pointers and suggestions on this will be appreciated

Comment: When you googled for Free Virtualization Software, what did you find?  Any questions about any of the products listed there?

Answer (score 1):

VMWare has several free products available [here](http://www.vmware.com/products/).  Microsoft also has some free options you should check out.  Just set up a virtual machine and start messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sun's [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is an open source virtualization product, which is a great way to get started.

> VirtualBox is a powerful x86 virtualization product for enterprise as well as home use. Not only is VirtualBox an extremely feature rich, high performance product for enterprise customers, it is also the only professional solution that is freely available as Open Source Software under the terms of the GNU General Public License (GPL).
>
> Presently, VirtualBox runs on Windows, Linux, Macintosh and OpenSolaris hosts and supports a large number of guest operating systems including but not limited to Windows (NT 4.0, 2000, XP, Server 2003, Vista, Windows 7), DOS/Windows 3.x, Linux (2.4 and 2.6), Solaris and OpenSolaris, and OpenBSD.